# JavaScript/jQuery: Use 'this' Object on Success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a somewhat annoying issue when it comes to sending an Ajax request to a server and then returning the data on the success function within an JavaScript object. I've searched for similar questions, but none were really of the same manner as mine.

For example, I have the following code for sending a request within an object:

```
function SomeObject ( someVar )
{
    var someVar = someVar;
}

SomeObject.prototype.sendRequest = function ()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url  : "somePage.php",
        type : "POST",
        data :
        {
            someVar : someVar
        },
        success : this.parseSuccess
    } );
};

SomeObject.prototype.parseSuccess = function ( data )
{
    if ( data === "success" )
    {
        this.proceed();  // Error
    }
    else
    {
        alert( "Server failed request." );
        this.proceed();
    }
};

SomeObject.prototype.proceed = function ()
{
    // Do something else
};
```

I know that `this.proceed()` will fail because `this` is not the `SomeObject` instance.

Still, how can I efficiently refer back to the object after the request is complete?
I found I could do the following to achieve what I want, but it does not feel proper, and I would like a better way to handle the Ajax calls:

```
SomeObject.prototype.sendRequest = function ()
{
    var me = this;

    $.ajax(
    {
        url  : "somePage.php",
        type : "POST",
        data :
        {
            someVar : someVar
        },
        success : function ( data )
        {
            me.parseSuccess( data );  // Will work
        }
    } );
};
```

Thanks for any help on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `context` option of `$.ajax`. Specifically, using `context: this` will set the `this` value inside `parseSuccess` to the current `this` value, which is what you want.

```
$.ajax({
  // ...
  context: this,
  success: this.parseSuccess
});
```

Comment: This solution worked. Now that I looked properly at the documentation, I feel a bit silly.

Answer (score 4):

You could always do this:

```
success : function ( data )
    {
        parseSuccess.apply(this, [data]); // or parseSuccess.call(this, data);
    }
```

Basically, with `apply()`, you can pass in the context of `this` you want to use inside the function, which in this case is the `SomeObject` context.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it would be `.call(this, data)` or `.apply(this, [data])`.

Comment: Ahh, right, forgot that `apply` wants an `arguments` array. I'll edit my answer to reflect that, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Doing this will yield `ReferenceError: parseSuccess is not defined`.